# How can Ruby's attr_accessor produce class variables or class instance variables instead of instance variables?

Tags: ruby, instance-variables, class-variables, class-instance-variables

If I have a class with an `attr_accessor`, it defaults to creating an instance variable along with the corresponding getters and setters. But instead of creating an instance variable, is there a way to get it to create a class variable or a class instance variable instead?

Comment: Work your way through "[Seeing Metaclasses Clearly](http://viewsourcecode.org/why/hacking/seeingMetaclassesClearly.html)"; it's very helpful when trying to understand the way Ruby's classes and objects work.

Answer (score 46):

Like this:

```
class TYourClass
  class << self
    attr_accessor :class_instance_variable
  end
end
```

You can look at this as opening the metaclass of the class (of which the class itself is an instance) and adding an attribute to it.

`attr_accessor` is a method of class `Class`, it adds two methods to the class, one which reads the instance variable, and other that sets it. Here's a possible implementation:

```
class Class
  def my_attr_accessor(name)
    define_method name do
      instance_variable_get "@#{name}"
    end 
    define_method "#{name}=" do |new_val|
      instance_variable_set "@#{name}", new_val
    end
  end
end
```

Completely untested class attribute accessor:

```
class Class
  def class_attr_accessor(name)
    define_method name do
      class_variable_get "@@#{name}"
    end 
    define_method "#{name}=" do |new_val|
      class_variable_set "@@#{name}", new_val
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I like your way of saying that it opens the metaclass of the class and sorts of adds an addendum. But why does it produce a class instance variable instead of a class variable? And would it be possible to get it to produce a class variable also or would this syntax only work for class instance variables?

Comment: I'ts different, see answer again

Comment: This will only work for class instance variables, b/c attr_* defines methods for instance variables (of some object).

Comment: There are some "," missing between arguments to instance_variable_set and class_variable_set but the edit is too small to submit.

Answer (score 21):

In Rails, (or anywhere you do `require 'active_support'`) you can use `cattr_accessor :name` to get the true class variable accessors.

The class instance variables that others have pointed out are usually more useful. The [APIdock `cattr_accessor` page](http://apidock.com/rails/Class/cattr_accessor) has some helpful discussion clarifying when you would want one not the other, plus the source to the `cattr_accessor`, `cattr_reader` and `cattr_writer` functions.

Comment: much easier - didn't know rails offered this.  Thanks!