# Access a module's class variables inside a class in Ruby

Tags: ruby, accessor, class-variables

I have a module with a class variable in it

```
module Abc
  @@variable = "huhu"

  def self.get_variable
    @@variable
  end

  class Hello
    def hola
      puts Abc.get_variable
    end
  end
end

a = Abc::Hello.new
a.hola
```

Is it possible to get `@@variable` inside `Hello` without using `get_variable` method? I mean something like `Abc.variable` would be nice. Just curious.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can Ruby's attr_accessor produce class variables or class instance variables instead of instance variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895747/how-can-rubys-attr-accessor-produce-class-variables-or-class-instance-variables)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot access `@@variable` directly (i.e., `Abc.variable`) within the scope of the `Hello` class in the module `Abc`. Why? Because, when the Ruby interpreter sees something like `Abc.variable`, it would think `variable` as class/module method of Abc.

It is important to think the Ruby way when programming in Ruby.

Comment: Aside note: If you wish to get over such thoughts to a large extent I have shared my learnings in the recently held Ruby Conf India 2011. Please do feel free to watch my talk at http://kartzontech.blogspot.com/2011/06/ruby-conf-india-2011.html and give your ratings and feedback. Most importantly, read the last of the slides where I mentioned the resources that helped shape my thinking the Ruby way.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
Abc.class_variable_get(:variable)
```

Comment: Please expand your code or supplement with an explanation or you risk having your answer deleted by the moderators.