# Why prepend Ruby method names with self?

Tags: ruby, syntax, methods

While looking over some Ruby code I noticed methods declared with `self.` prepended to the method name. For example:

```
def self.someMethod
  //...
end
```

What does prepending `self.` to the method name change about the method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`def self.something` is a class method, called with:

```
Class.some_method
```

`def something` is an instance method, called with:

```
class = Class.new
class.some_method
```

The difference is that one is called on the class itself, the other on **an instance** of the class.

To define a class method, you can also use the class name, however that will make things more difficult to refactor in the future as the class name may change.

Some sample code:

```
class Foo
  def self.a
    "a class method"
  end

  def b
    "an instance method"
  end

  def Foo.c
    "another class method"
  end
end

Foo.a # "a class method"
Foo.b # NoMethodError
Foo.c # "another class method"
bar = Foo.new 
bar.a # NoMethodError
bar.b # "an instance method"
bar.c # NoMethodError
```

Comment: Interesting. `self` isn't the first keyword I would associate with a class method.

Comment: You can also use the class name, I have edited my answer to show this.

Comment: Are static variables accessed in a similar manner? Perhaps like this: `self.someVariable`?

Comment: @MrMusic, in the ruby world, they are called class variables, they are initialized with the double @@ syntax `@@class_variable` I would recommend creating "getter" and "setter" methods for them.  This answer may be of use.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895747/how-can-rubys-attr-accessor-produce-class-variables-or-class-instance-variables

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm still unclear about the significance of `self.` when accessing a variable.

Comment: self is not associated with class methods. It creates a class method in that context only because self is a class.

Answer (score 3):

The self. causes it to become a class method, rather than an instance method. This is similar to static functions in other languages.