# Class method in Ruby (equivalent of static in JAVA)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Folks, I am learning ruby and recently moved from JAVA. In JAVA I could make a member variable of a class static and that member variable would remain the same across instances of the class. How do I achieve the same in ruby. I did something like this in my ruby class:

```
class Baseclass

  @@wordshash

end
```

This seems to serve the purpose so far while I am testing this, that is @@wordhash remains the same across instances of Baseclass. Is my understanding correct.

Also, I wanted to have a member method in the class that is equivalent of a static method in JAVA(I do not require to have an instance of the class to access this). How can I do this? For example I want to have a method in the Baseclass like getwordshash() which returns @@wordshash and the user of that method should not have to make an instance of Baseclass().So something like this:

```
class Baseclass

  @@wordshash

  #static or class method
  def getwordhash()
    return @@wordshash
  end
end
```

and then I can use it like

```
#without making an instance
@hash = Baseclass.getwordhash()
```

I apologize if this is a very naive question, i am really new to ruby but very excited to learn.

Answer (score 13):

Using class variables as static store has unintended consequences in sub classes. You can easily implement static store by declaring an instance variable at the class level.

```
class Foo

  # initialize a static variable
  @names = ['Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry']

  # class method (notice the self. prefix
  def self.names
    @names
  end

  # instance methods

  def names
    @names
  end

  def names=val
    @names = val
  end

end
```

Let us print the static names

```
>> Foo.names
=> ["Tom", "Dick", "Harry"]
```

Let us print the instance variable

```
>> f = Foo.new
>> f.names
=> nil
```

Let us set the instance variable and try to print it again

```
>> f.names=["Bob", "Danny"]
=> ["Bob", "Danny"]

>> f.names
=> ["Bob", "Danny"]
```

Let us print the static variable again

```
>> Foo.names
=> ["Tom", "Dick", "Harry"]
```

I use the term `static` loosely. In reality both variables are instance variables. The `@names` declared in the class context is an instance variable for the `Foo` class object and `@names` inside a method is the instance variable of an instance of `Foo` class. Since there will ever be one object representing the type `Foo`, we can consider `@names` declared in the class context to be a static variable.

Comment: is it possible to use some variation of the shorthand: `attr_accessor` for access to these quasi class instance variables?

Comment: @DennisHodapp have you tried using `cattr_accessor` and `mattr_accessor` methods?

Comment: no I haven't, but it seems those accessors are extensions of rails and I would rather not have to import them for a Ruby application.

Comment: @DennisHodapp, you don't need the entire rails for the feature. You just need ActiveSupport gem(http://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport). Here is a another way to use `attr_accessor` to do the same: http://stackoverflow.com/a/895752/163203

Answer (score 7):

```
def self.getwordhash
  @@wordshash
end
```

With [Ruby and Rails Naming Conventions](http://itsignals.cascadia.com.au/?p=7):

```
class Baseclass

  @@words_hash = Hash.new

  def self.words_hash
    @@words_hash
  end
end
```

Comment: Actually, convention doesn't usually have the type. It would be `@@words` rather than `@@words_hash`.