# Attr_accessor on class variables

Tags: ruby

`attr_accessor` does not work on the following code. The error says  "`undefined method 'things' for Parent:Class (NoMethodError)`":

```
class Parent
  @@things = []
  attr_accessor :things
end
Parent.things << :car

p Parent.things
```

However the following code works

```
class Parent
  @@things = []
  def self.things
    @@things
  end
  def things
    @@things
  end
end
Parent.things << :car

p Parent.things
```

Comment: attr_accessor is ruby's shorthand for creating setter and getter on an instance of the object(as well as instance variables) and is not meant for use on class level variables

Comment: Though I know practically nothing of Rails, I believe with `require 'active_support'`, you could use [cattr_accessor :things](http://apidock.com/rails/Class/cattr_accessor).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895747/how-can-rubys-attr-accessor-produce-class-variables-or-class-instance-variables

Answer (score 118, accepted):

`attr_accessor` defines accessor methods for an instance. If you want class level auto-generated accessors you could use it on the metaclass

```
class Parent
  @things = []

  class << self
    attr_accessor :things
  end
end

Parent.things #=> []
Parent.things << :car
Parent.things #=> [:car]
```

but note that this creates a class level instance variable *not* a class variable. This is likely what you want anyway, as class variables behave differently than you might expect when dealing w/ inheritance. See "[Class and Instance Variables In Ruby](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/)".

Comment: This still return the same error. class Parent
  @@things = []
  class << self
    attr_accessor :things
  end
end
Parent.things << :car

p Parent.things

Comment: See my edit - I added in the initialization for you. Since it's a class level instance var not a class variable you need to only use one `@`

Comment: What if I only want `@things` available within the class? For instance variable I can just `attr_reader`, but for class level instance variable I have to rely on `attr_accessor` to write to it myself (assume that it's not an array, but something immutable like an integer).

Comment: "a class level instance var not a class variable" -- I feel like half of answers tells to do the one kind, another half tells to do another. Still no one said what's the difference and how to choose between them.

Answer (score 19):

`attr_accessor` generates accessors for *instance* variables. Class variables in Ruby are a very different thing, and they are usually not what you want. What you probably want here is a class instance variable. You can use `attr_accessor` with class instance variables like so:

```rb
class Something
  class << self
    attr_accessor :things
  end
end
```

Then you can write `Something.things = 12` and it will work.

Comment: In this case if a class inherits Something, does the instance of inherited class object get a new copy of things, right?

Comment: @Talespin_Kit: Correct — each class will have its own `@things` variable, because instance variables are specific to the object that owns them.

Answer (score 5):

Just some clarification: class variables won't be accessible using `attr_accessor`. It's all about instance variables:

```
class SomeClass
  class << self
    attr_accessor :things
  end
  @things = []
end
```

because in Ruby, class is an instance of the class "Class" (God, I love to say that) and `attr_accessor` sets accessor methods for instance variables.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably the simplest way.

```
class Parent
  def self.things
    @@things ||= []
  end
end
Parent.things << :car

p Parent.things
```

Answer (score 1):

Аlso note that a **singleton method** is a method only for a single object. In Ruby, a Class is also an object, so it too can have singleton methods! So be aware of when you might be calling them.

Example:

```
class SomeClass
  class << self
    def test
    end
  end
end

test_obj = SomeClass.new

def test_obj.test_2
end

class << test_obj
  def test_3
  end
end

puts "Singleton methods of SomeClass"
puts SomeClass.singleton_methods
puts '------------------------------------------'
puts "Singleton methods of test_obj"
puts test_obj.singleton_methods
```

Singleton methods of SomeClass

***test***

---

Singleton methods of test_obj

***test_2***

***test_3***

Answer (score 1):

```
Parent.class_variable_get(:@@things)
```

That would be the built-in way. In most cases this should be sufficient I think. No need to have a class variable accessor in the instance.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Parent
  @things = []
  
  singleton_class.send(:attr_accessor, :things)
end
```

This pattern is most useful when you are defining accessors dynamically or creating them inside a method:

```
class Foo
  def self.add_accessor(name)
    singleton_class.send(:attr_accessor, name)
  end
end

Foo.add_accessor :things
Foo.things = [:car]
Foo.things # => [:car]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is `class_attribute`

```rb
class Base
  class_attribute :foo
  self.foo = '--UNSET--'

  def show
    puts self.foo
  end
end

class X < Base
  self.foo = 'XXX'
end

class Y < Base
  self.foo = 'YYY'
end

class Z < Base
end

puts X.foo # -> 'XXX'
puts Y.foo # -> 'YYY'
puts Z.foo # -> '--UNSET--'
X.new.show # -> 'XXX'
X.foo = 'x-x-x'
X.new.show # -> 'x-x-x'
Y.new.show # -> 'YYY'
```