# Static variables versus eigenclass class variables, what's the difference in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I guess I'm asking for the difference between `@store` and `@@store` in the following:

```
class Test
  @@store = 9 
  class << self
    def set_store(v)
      @store = v
    end
    def store
      @store
    end
    def sstore
      @@store
    end
  end
end

Test.set_store 8
p Test.store # 8 
p Test.sstore # 9

a = Test.new

p a.class.store # 8
p a.class.sstore # 9
```

Where are static variables attached to if not the eigenclass? Are the two effectively the same in terms of interaction?

Comment: @@variables are shared within class hierarchy (and class instances), class-level @variables are not.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I guess the https://stackoverflow.com/q/21122691/322020 lacks your comment/answer because there people advise two different things not explaining how to choose between.

Comment: Also mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/5890199/322020

Comment: @Nakilon: haha, I'm flattered that you think I'm some kind of expert on class variables. :) I've looked through the posts you linked and they look okay-ish to me. Not sure a full answer is needed there. But feel free to post this clarification yourself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are both class variables but in an instance you can access only @@store variable.

Mind that class variables are not thread safe in Ruby, so use Mutex if you plan to use varaible as a Hash.

[Using class instance variable for mutex in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21735401/using-class-instance-variable-for-mutex-in-ruby)

Comment: I suppose you can access them via `self.class.`